# How to switch layout by user agent

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am creating a website with the Phoenix framework.

I would like to use a different layout and template depending if the user uses PC or a smartphone.

So, I would like to switch layout and template by checking user agent.

What is the best way to check user agent and switch layout and template?
Or, Do you know any useful library to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this easily in a plug. The `conn` struct passed to your plug has a `:req_headers` key that will contain among other headers the `"user-agent"`. You can either use that directly or use a parsing library like https://github.com/elixytics/ua_inspector to conditionalize your layout selection. You can then choose the layout with `Phoenix.Controller.put_layout/2` https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#put_layout/2

For Example using ua_inspector:

```
  def some_plug(conn) do
    ua = get_req_header(conn, "user-agent")
    case UAInspector.parse(ua).os.name do
      "iOS" -> Phoenix.Controller.put_layout(conn, "mobile")
      _ -> Phoenix.Controller.put_layout(conn, "desktop")
    end
  end
```